# RxSwift generic `Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> [Any]' to expected argument type '(String) -> _'`

Tags: swift, generics, rx-swift

I want to create an extension of `ObservableType`, but the following code doesn't compile.

```
public extension ObservableType {
  public func foo<C: Collection>(_ calls: @escaping (E) -> C) -> Observable<[Any]> where C.Iterator.Element: ObservableType {
    return flatMap { input in Observable.zip(calls(input)) { objects in objects }
    }
  }
}

// compile error
Observable.just("foo")
  .foo { foo in
    [Observable.just(User()), Observable.just(Repo())]
  }
```

It throws an error: `Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> [Any]' to expected argument type '(String) -> _'`

I have no idea where the problem is. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you return an array of two different types - `User` and `Repo`. If you change the return value to this one, for instance:

`return [Observable.just(User()), Observable.just(User())]` - it will work as expected.

**Updated:** In your case you can achive it so:

`[Observable<Any>.just(User()), Observable<Any>.just(Repo())]`

**Updated:** More correct to use the following return type for `foo` function - `Observable<[C.Element.E]>` IMHO.

Comment: How about I want mixed types?

Comment: Is it possible to modify the `foo` function to make client code compile without error?

Comment: @akabc I don't see the another solution. We have to specify a Collection.Element type for `zip` function. 1) Either we work only with `User` or `Repo` or cast to `Any` type, as in my updated answer.